# Stop checking the checkbox by clicking on the caption to DevExpress TreeList control

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I'm using CheckedListBoxControl of DevExpress (v18.1). When I click on the text/Caption of a list item then this item's checkbox is checked. However, I just want to check an item when I click directly on the checkbox. Can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the CheckedListBoxControl's [SelectionMode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseListBoxControl.SelectionMode.property) property to SelectionMode.MultiSimple